# Modifying plural form of views_edit in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to change default `Draft` text for my custom post type views, and I found a function that could do this:

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-custom_post_type_name', 'custom_draft_name', 10, 1);

if (!function_exists('custom_draft_name')) {
    function custom_draft_name( $views ) {
        if (isset($views['draft']) && $views['draft'] != '') {
            $views['draft'] = str_replace(esc_html__('Draft', 'custom_post_type_name'), esc_html__('Unapproved', 'custom_post_type_name'), $views['draft']);
            print_r($draft_array);
        }

        return $views;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I get only singular change for this. So if I had one `Draft` I'll have one `Unapproved`. But when I have more than one I'll have two `Drafts` and automatically I'll have two `Unapproveds`. Which is terrible. It should be two unapproved. So I tried to use `_n()` for the plurals, by creating an array to check against with my `str_replace`:

```
add_filter( 'views_edit-custom_post_type_name', 'custom_draft_name', 10, 1);

if (!function_exists('custom_draft_name')) {
    function custom_draft_name( $views ) {
        if (isset($views['draft']) && $views['draft'] != '') {
            $draft_array = array(esc_html__('Draft', 'custom_post_type_name'), _n('Draft', 'Drafts' , 10, 'custom_post_type_name'));
            $views['draft'] = str_replace($draft_array, esc_html__('Unapproved', 'custom_post_type_name'), $views['draft']);
            print_r($draft_array);
        }

        return $views;
    }
}
```

But I still get `Unapproveds` instead `Unapproved`.

Any help how to solve this?

** ANSWER **

And once again I found the solution immediately after I post on SO xD

Just do a `wp_count_posts('custom_post_type')` like

```
$custom_posts = wp_count_posts('custom_post_type_name');
if($custom_posts->draft == 1){
    $views['draft'] = str_replace(esc_html__('Draft', 'custom_post_type_name'), esc_html__('Unapproved', 'custom_post_type_name'), $views['draft']);
} else{
    $views['draft'] = str_replace(esc_html__('Drafts', 'custom_post_type_name'), esc_html__('Unapproved', 'custom_post_type_name'), $views['draft']);
}
```